# IBAForms issues in iOS6

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have an app that uses [IBAForms](https://github.com/ittybittydude/IBAForms).  When running in the XCode 4.5GM iOS6 simulator I'm finding the app hangs frequently when an `IBAFormViewController` has it's `formDataSource` reset.  Note that it doesn't happen on the FIRST `setFormDataSource`, but it does happen on subsequent calls to `setFormDataSource`.

I narrowed the problem down to a hack that IBAForms uses to enable off-screen table view cells to work with the UIResponder chain ("`hiddenCellCache`").  Basically, as cells are reparented to nil by the UITableView, they place themselves in a hidden window.

When I disabled this process (changes shown below) my hangs went away.

My theory is that iOS6 tableviews have some new optimization for cleaning up hidden cells which is somehow now incompatible with IBAForms's hiddenCellCache.  **But I'd like to understand this better.**

For reference, here are the changes I made to IBAForms.  If they prove to work well I'll submit them back to the project on GitHub.

IBAFormFieldCell.m:

```
// change is to remove an assert on hiddenCellCache
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
    if (self.window == nil) {

        [self.hiddenCellCache addSubview:self];
    }
}
```

IBAFormViewController.m:

```
// this setter also sets the datasource of the tableView and reloads the table
- (void)setFormDataSource:(IBAFormDataSource *)dataSource {
    if (dataSource != formDataSource_) {

        //$$TS modified to work with iOS6
        for (IBAFormFieldCell* c in self.hiddenCellCache.subviews)
        {
            c.hiddenCellCache = nil;
            [c removeFromSuperview];
        }

        IBAFormDataSource *oldDataSource = formDataSource_;
        formDataSource_ = [dataSource retain];
        IBA_RELEASE_SAFELY(oldDataSource);

        self.tableView.dataSource = formDataSource_;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- sanity check - is this a problem for anyone else?
- what is it about the hiddenCellCache hack that causes it to break in iOS6?

**EDIT**:  here's another simpler "fix".  When I ran the app in the profiler I noticed that during the hang the app was spending all it's time in UITableViewCell layoutSubviews.  I still don't understand why.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    if ( self.superview == self.hiddenCellCache )
        return;
    
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Have you put your app through Instruments to see what it's doing while it's hanging the main thread? Can you also link me to your github fork?

Comment: Yeah, just did.  It's spending all its time in UITableViewCell / layoutSubviews.  This led to a different fix, which I added to the question.  I still don't understand the root cause.

Comment: If you can post a working code sample for me to try I'll look into this today. I'm using IBAForms in iOS6 and I'm not seeing your issues in my code. I'm keen to help though.

Answer (score -1):

-(void)layoutSubviews method seems to do the fix. Thanks TomSwift.